# MySQL Queries for a tool shop

Tags: mysql

I have to create a database for a tool shop and since I am not able to get MySQL running, because of my computer, I wanted to ask for help with my queries.

I have several entities, like customer, car, repair, repair team member, employee, service, tire storage, personal file, sales.

Now I have to do following queries:

1. Sort every car that contains the combination "123" inside the vehicle identification number. (Result column: VehicleID)
   Here I would say SELECT * FROM Vehicle WHERE VIN = '%123%';
2. A list of every sales in 2021. (Result column: document number)
   Here I don't know how to connect both entities (service, sales) and filter by year.
3. The total revenue generated from sales in 2020
4. An overview of all the sales to the customer with the customer ID "4711" (Result column: Date of sale, product number, price)

What about -> SELECT * FROM Verkauf WHERE Verkauf.Dienstleistung_D_ID IN ( SELECT D_ID FROM Dienstleistung WHERE Kunde_K_ID == "K4711" )

5. Overview of all customers who have been sold something by an employee with employment year before 2010. The output should be sorted by last name and first name of the customer. (Result columns: Customer number, first name, last name, personnel number, last name of employee, year of employment).

I hope you can help me, since I am not able to create the code, even with SQLite, MySQL etc. so I am not able to test my queries and hope that you can help me.

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT0Xt.png)

My ER diagram is in German, I hope you understand the structure.

Reparatur - repair,
Fahrzeug - car,
Kunde - customer ,
Dienstleistung - service,
Verkauf - sales ,
Reifenlagerung - tire storage,
Reparaturteammitglied - repair team member,
Mitarbeiter - employee,
Personalakte - personal file,

Comment: You can always use an online service like, for example, https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: With db-fiddle.com I only get problems.  ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table test.... doesn't exist, but I don't even find a single entry that contains "test", so I am not able to fix this. That's why I ask for help with the queries.

My queries so far:

1. SELECT * FROM Vehicle WHERE VIN = '%123%' -> To get a list of every car, with a VIN containing any combination with 123.

2. SELECT Verkauf.D_ID, Verkauf.V_ID, Verkauf.Belegnummer, Verkauf.Summe, Dienstleistung.Kosten, Dienstleistung.Datum
FROM Verkauf
INNER JOIN Dienstleistung ON Verkauf.D_ID=Dienstleistung.D_ID
WHERE Datum LIKE '%2021'
;